# SQL Server Logical Reads

Tags: sql-server

We have the same database setup on two machines.  Same tables.  Same indexes.  I am running a query that is self joining:

```
   SELECT Column1 
         ,Column2 
         ,Column3
         ,Column4
         ,RowID    = RowNumber OVER ( Partition By Column1, ORDER BY Column2)
     INTO #tmp
     FROM AuditTable

   SELECT * 
     FROM #tmp t1 
     JOIN #tmp t2 ON t2.Column1 = t1.Column1 
                 AND t2.RowiD   = t1.RowID +1
```

We run this query with 20,000 rows on one database/server and it takes 2 minutes to complete with logical reads around 3.2 million.
The same query runs on a different database/server with 150,000 records and returns in a second with logical reads of 2240.  What about the servers would make the same query on the same table setup (including indexes / fragmentation/ statistics) run so differently on two different servers

Comment: What do the execution plans look like?

Comment: are you accessing both database from same machine ?

Comment: It returns 20,000 rows or are there 20,000 rows in the AuditTable?

Comment: there are 20000 rows / 150,000 in the audit tables

Comment: the two databases are on two different servers (which was mentioned in the original post)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your servers have different performance.

However, in SQL Server 2012+, you should be using `LAG()`:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4,
       LAG(Column2) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column2) as prev_Column2,
       LAG(Column3) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column2) as prev_Column3
FROM AuditTable;
```

And, in order versions of SQL Server, you should not use a temporary table, unless you are going to add indexes to it for performance.  A CTE is simpler and doesn't require materializing the intermediate results.